# Narcissistic personality recent studies

Tags: reference-request, personality, personality-disorder

I have recently read the Nancy McWilliams' book "Psychoanalytic Diagnosis" and learned that serious studies on narcissistic personality were done mostly in the end of the XXth century. However her book does not contain any reference dating in recent 28 years. I doubt the research in this direction has just abruptly stopped.

Could you please point me to some particular references or more generally authors who are thought to have made some significant contributions to this field in relatively recent years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I have found an answer, more or less. There is a person called Sam Vaknin, who published a book called "Malignant self-love". Even though Vaknin is not an academic himself, the book does contain references to more recent studies.

Comment: And, actually, one really recent book "Rethinking Narcissism" is by Craig Malkin, who is an academic.